# QT QMediaResource::AudioBitrate() return 0

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I am trying to use QMediaResource::audioBitRate() to get audio bitrate, but result is always 0.

How i can get audio bitrate from audio file using QMediaResource::audioBitRate()?

I use qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.0.exe download from here https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.0/

i have `QT += multimedia` in *.pro file

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaResource>

QMediaResource audioFile(QUrl::fromLocalFile("song.mp3"));
int audioBitrate = audioFile.audioBitRate();
QString bitrate = QString(audioBitrate);
QMessageBox::information(this,"title",bitrate,"ok");
```

Comment: There is no single question in this posting yet. And http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number QString::number is probably the better way to convert the integer to string.

Comment: @AlexanderVX the result is same

Comment: Try to check this mp3 file in another media player, maybe it has a variable bitrate.

Comment: I can never trust what Qt Multimedia does and write own plug-ins for video. Otherwise nothing works on single-board device. Even with PC it is a game.